# ios How to run method on every day?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to check for update of the stored db every day or every X interval of day, how is it possible to call a method on every X interval of day? I found some code that is for the x interval of seconds, is it feasible to do by the same way? And main thing is it should run in background too. I also though of the way by storing the last updated date in database so that I retrive every time app lunch and compare with present date? Please help me by suggesting the better way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't really run any app in background unless you are playing audio, doing something thing with the location or a re an voip client, you will need to do this when the user opens your app.

Just store the last update date in the `NSUserDefault`

Comment: can you please suggest the way to do it?

Comment: Store the date in the `NSUserDefault` then when the user launches the app check wether the date is older then a dat. If so run the update method. After successfully done the update store the current date in the `NSUserDefault`

Comment: thanks, I will do some research about NSUserDefault, cause I haven't used it before.

Answer (score 0):

You can not execute your application when it is closed. You can not create background applications or daemons.

Maybe running it on application start would be appropriate for you, but if you need information from the device every day, the user will have to make sure the app is open every day.